# Performance issues aftrer adding compose view in android project

Tags: android, performance, android-jetpack-compose

I'm working on multi-module android app and we desided to add Jatpack Compose to create some ui. Just after adding a compose view in xml layout, the frames droped for almost 2 sec! (even without any content in it). Any suggestions to fix that issue?

I tried:

- to implement compose view in different modules with simple ui, but result the same, difference just in millis of frames dropes.
- to build a release version of the app. Didn't help.
- to checked on a few Samsung devices and emulators, same result everywhere.
- to run test app with empty activity and one View in layout, same result.

The messages I got in log:

```
I/Choreographer: Skipped 101 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
I/OpenGLRenderer: Davey! duration=2619ms; Flags=1, IntendedVsync=6245917882999, Vsync=6246801216297, OldestInputEvent=9223372036854775807, NewestInputEvent=0, HandleInputStart=6246808163500, AnimationStart=6246808221500, PerformTraversalsStart=6246832702800, DrawStart=6248413688200, SyncQueued=6248491709800, SyncStart=6248492385600, IssueDrawCommandsStart=6248492634200, SwapBuffers=6248534040100, FrameCompleted=6248537882900, DequeueBufferDuration=358000, QueueBufferDuration=596000, 
I/OpenGLRenderer: Davey! duration=2016ms; Flags=0, IntendedVsync=6246817753107, Vsync=6248501086373, OldestInputEvent=9223372036854775807, NewestInputEvent=0, HandleInputStart=6248512412400, AnimationStart=6248512476300, PerformTraversalsStart=6248772539800, DrawStart=6248776848800, SyncQueued=6248829399900, SyncStart=6248830783000, IssueDrawCommandsStart=6248831155000, SwapBuffers=6248832726000, FrameCompleted=6248836100200, DequeueBufferDuration=624000, QueueBufferDuration=714000,
```

versions:
kotlin_version = '1.6.21';
compose_version = '1.2.0-rc03'
Also tried to update versions to kotlin_version = '1.7.0' and compose_version = '1.2.0' stable; Didn't help;

dependencies:

```
compose = [
["androidx.compose.material:material:$compose_version"],
["androidx.compose.animation:animation:$compose_version"],
["androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_version"],
["androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_version"],
["androidx.compose.runtime:runtime:$compose_version"],
["androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-livedata:$compose_version"],
['androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:2.4.1'],
['androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.4.0'],
]
```

Android Studio Chipmunk | 2021.2.1
Build #AI-212.5712.43.2112.8512546, built on April 28, 2022
Runtime version: 11.0.12+7-b1504.28-7817840 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by Oracle Corporation
Windows 10 10.0
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 1280M
Cores: 8
Registry: external.system.auto.import.disabled=true
Non-Bundled Plugins: wu.seal.tool.jsontokotlin (3.7.4), org.jetbrains.kotlin (212-1.7.10-release-333-AS5457.46)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.